# Help with CSS selectors (jQuery datepicker)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm tyring to style the jQuery datepicker. I can't use a jQuery theme as it wrecks the rest of my site.

I've got it all working expect for one bit - highlighting the current day.

The problem I'm having is that when the datepicker first loads the current day is displayed as follows:

```
<td class="ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-today">
    <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-hover" href="#">14</a>
</td>
```

When the user hovers over any other day, the `ui-state-hover` on the current day is removed, and then the current day highlighting works ok:

```
<td class="ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-today">
    <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">14</a>
</td>
```

My CSS for the hover state is like:

`.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover { ... }`

and on-load this is overwriting my `ui-state-highlight` which highlights the current day.

I've tried to do:

`.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight .ui-state-hover  { ... }`

Which I thought would preferentially match as it's a more specific selector, but it's not working.

So the question is, how can I make `.ui-state-highlight .ui-state-hover` override `.ui-state-hover` so I don't lose my highlight on hover?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal but you could add the `!important` to each of your styles inside your selector to override it wity your own style:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover {
  color: '#00ff00' !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the element in order to raise it's place on the hierachy `td.ui-widget-content td.ui-state-hover` for example. Also, perhaps not the most elegant solution, but adding a style inline or on the actual html page as a header within the `<style></style` tags would take precedence over any other stylesheets provided that it's the one last called.